# Making a C function pointer work with C-style stack based calling mechanics in C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, function, pointers

I want to call a pure C style function from a dll in my C++ program. I tried casting my function pointer using `reinterpret_cast` to `__cdecl` and still the calling convention of `_stdcall` seems to be preserved. I am new to Windows C++ programming.

**Edit** Code from comment

```
reinterpret_cast< Error ( __cdecl*)(int,int)> (GetProcAddress(Mydll::GetInstance()->ReturnDLLInstance(), "add"))(1,10)
```

is my call. The actual function syntax seems to have been declared as

```
Error __cdecl add(int,int);
```

Debugger throws me the error **run time check failure #0**. I am working in Windows-C++

Comment: @mani post the code by editing your question

Comment: @Bo and mattst88: what if i am not able to access my c code?? I am using getprocaddress to get my dll's exported function. Thanks everyone for your response!  @Neil-I am sorry for the clumsy post-I will edit it.

Comment: @Rob-apologies and thanks for cleaning up the mess-that was my post..

Comment: While the answers below point out the solution, I was reminded of this recent post on The Old New Thing: "A function pointer cast is a bug waiting to happen": http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/06/10161590.aspx

Comment: @Zenzelzz Thanks. So are you suggesting me that I have a bug which I cannot hope to get cleared up today or tomorrow :D ?? To be very clear, i want to import a c style function from a dll in my c++ code and i cannot play with the dll...would appreciate it if you have any suggestions!!

Comment: I tried casting it using this idea suggested by another guy  [code guru forums](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-70673.html) . Nothing seems to help :(

Comment: @all got it running..the code in the link i posted above did the deal...Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me out!

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-70673.html

Answer (score 8):

I believe the solution to your question is 'extern "C" { ...'

See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html#faq-32.3

Answer (score 6):

Usually you need to use extern "C" for this...

--- c_code.h ---

```
void func(int arg);
void (*func_ptr)(int arg);
```

--- cpp_code.cpp ---

```
extern "C" void func(int arg);
extern "C" void (*func_ptr)(int arg);

int main()
{
    func(20);
    *func_ptr(20);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two things at work over here.

The first is the calling convention. The calling convention is a part of the Application Binary Interface (ABI) that decides whether the caller or the callee is responsible for cleaning up the stack. If you want your functions to behave correctly both you harness and your dll will need to use the same calling convention. In WIN32 APIs this is typically __stdcall although C typically uses __cdecl.

The other issue is name mangling. Since the arguments of a function form part of the function signature in C++ (to allow for function overloading) this information is incorporated into the symbol table of you object code. This will typically be a whole bunch of extra strange characters. C does not need to do name mangling since it does not allow function overloading.

Sometimes in C++ you want to call C functions (ie C function symbols compiled by a C and not a C++ compiler). In such a case you need to define the function in an `extern "C" {}` block.

Hopefully this will help you out

Comment: my dll function uses __cdecl convention. My function pointer uses the same..And as for your second suggestion I guess you are saying what the other two guys said. but  i dont have the liberty to use extern for my c functions or for that matter do anything with it. is there any other way to work around it? Thanks for your response anyway :)

Comment: if you cannot edit the C header file put the extern "C" round the #include directive e.g. extern "C" { \r #include "myCHeader.h" \r }

Comment: at the risk of being irksome, i have one more question. I have a dll and I just  use getprocaddress and load library to get the function from the dll. What do you mean by enclosing the header file in extern block. If i sound like a novice that's what I am :D